# Design generic attachments SQL Table/Entity in EF Code-First

Tags: sql, database-design, ef-code-first

In my system, many entities requires to have attachments.

For example, the Mission entity requires its own attachments, also the Activity, Projects and so on.

The question is how to design the Attachments table?

1. Attachment table per entity, like MissionsAttachments, ActivitiesAttachments etc.?
2. One table for all the attachments in the system? if so, what would be the identifiers for each attachment?

Any idea of how can I create a generic attachment table that will serve the whole system?

Comment: The problem is that not all of the responses are answers.

Comment: Marc, I just reviewed my question's answers and mark as answer few responses.

Comment: Seems like you are inclined to have a single Attachment table either way. Why then are you still considering separate tables for different entities? Is that because different entities expect different sets of attributes for their attachments?

Comment: Hi Andriy, No.. I do need a generic table, it was just an example of what I need. Do you have some idea for a generic table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just have one table for attachments and one table to account for the entities.  For example:

```
Entities Table:
==============
EntityId
EntityName

Attachments Table:
=================
AttachmentId
EntityId
Attachment
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a generic attachments table, you could do the following:

```
create table attachments 
(attachment_id int not null, 
 parent_id int not null, 
 parent_type varchar(32) not null, 
  other_cols_here, 
 primary key(attachment_id))
```

This would allow you to have independent entity tables (so you don't have to always have a row in some generic table for mission, activity, etc). To find the attachment for, say, a mission, you'd have to do: `select * from attachments where parent_id = MISSION_ID and parent_type = 'mission'`

The downside to this, of course, is that you give up the ability to have a foreign key constraint on the mission table for parent_id.